# Increase memory for ant

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, ant, ram

I have an issue about memory usage.
I had 8 GB of RAM and I had my ant settings like this:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2G
```

Now, I have installed 16 GB of RAM but when I run an ant clean all, this take the same time to compile.

How I have to set the options to increase memory and speed? I have Windows 7 64bit and 16 GB RAM. I use Eclipse, but I run ant clean all and server Tomcat from the cmd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have strange configuration - `PermGen` size is four times bigger than a `Heap`. Maybe it is a typo? Try this:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

But there is no much to do with `ant` - big project needs a long time to build. Do not forget, that this process can consume much `CPU` (then it's good idea to make `ant` use multiple threads [by parallel tasks](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) or [custom runtime](http://blog.codeaholics.org/parallel-ant/)) or have `HDD` bottleneck (consider using `SSD` or even `RAM drive` in this case)

Comment: Good I passed from 20 minutes to 7 minutes for an ant clean all

Comment: nice, I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Hey!  I am trying to run ant rebuild command from command line.  Unfortunately it is taking ~40 min every time.  I am using JBoss server so every time I run rebuild and deploy to jboss and start jbos taking ~one hour.  Can I speed it up by setting ANT_OPTS ? my machine is 32G ram.